# how to change the default server value in p4 info

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

I am getting below error.

```
C:\Users\sanisett>p4 info

Perforce client error:
    Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
    TCP connect to perforce:1666 failed.
    connect: 192.168.104.92:1666: WSAETIMEDOUT
```

If I am passing the server details as a parameter using -p I am getting proper o/p like

```
p4 -p servername:port info.
```

Kindly share how to change the default server details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do it:

```
p4 set P4PORT=servername:port
```